# How to install jQuery typings (for using its functions in an Angular 2 component)?

Tags: angular

I need to use some jQuery plugins in Angular 2 project, so I need to call jQuery functions in my A2 components.

I found advice to install ts typings for jQuery and then declare jQuery in an A2 component: `declare var $:JQueryStatic;`

I tried to install typings this way: `tsd install jquery --save` but got `zero results` message...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `npm install @types/jquery`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Typescript >=2.x.x, typings are now installed from NPM. For example, the typings package for jQuery is [@types/jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40types%2Fjquery) for jQuery 1.10.x.

Install using the following:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```